# Как создать diff базы данных PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, hibernate

Есть БД на PostgreSQL. Необходимо передавать состояние некоторых таблиц с определённой периодичностью, например, раз в сутки. Ввиду того, что данных может быть очень много, необходимо передавать так называемый diff, а полный "снимок" бд делать реже. Как реализовать этот diff. Можно ли на Postgres сделать такой запрос (или сделать это средствами hibernate), который позволял бы проверять были ли изменения по этому полю, например за сутки и какой это запрос? (реализуется всё на Java, orm hibernate, json(jackson), spring).

Comment: что бы выдать разницу, должно быть с чем сравнивать. предположим вы добавите во все таблицы поле с датой последнего изменения, по нему вы легко найдете строки, которые добавились или модифицировались с определенной даты. Но вот удаленных строк вы уже не увидите ...

Comment: И ещё, как должен храниться этот diff, в виде таблицы?

Comment: ну теоретически да, можно такую же таблицу, как основная, только с колонкой тип изменения. в которой будет признак что запись удалена, добавлена или изменена. При желании можно вести ее триггером на основной таблице, фиксируя все изменения. но если таблиц много такой подход будет мягко говоря сложным. вам же потом все эти логи изменений еще применять на целевой системе

Comment: В общем я бы предложил не изобретать велосипеды. А воспользоваться полноценной репликацией. Или использовать oracle golden gate, если стандартная репликация чем то не подходит

Comment: @Mike , спасибо за помощь, постараюсь во всё это вникнуть

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если нужно вести, что то вроде журнала изменений, то можно попробовать автономные транзакции. Можно будет отловить все. Даже если был rollback можно будет увидеть что хотели изменить. Это как вариант
http://blog.dalibo.com/2016/08/19/Autonoumous_transactions_support_in_PostgreSQL.html

А если цель резервное копирование, то да репликация. Хотя одно другому не мешает.